# Why do my obstacles float above the ground? Unity2D

Tags: c#, 2d, unity, object-pools

I'm making an infinite runner game and I'm trying to spawn obstacles, but all of them float far above the ground instead of being at the ground level.

[image: How the summoned obstacles float above the ground when the game is running.]

This is the code on summoning the bears.

> PlatformGenerator Class

```
    if (Random.Range (0f, 100f) < randomEnemyThreshold) 
        {
            GameObject newEnemy = enemyPool.GetPooledObject();

            Vector3 enemyPosition = new Vector3 (0f, 0f, 0f);

            newEnemy.transform.position = transform.position + enemyPosition;
            newEnemy.transform.rotation = transform.rotation;
            newEnemy.SetActive(true);
        }
```

Ask me more about the game if you need more information.

Edit:

Here is the whole class.

> The PlatformGenerator Class

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlatformGenerator : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject thePlatform;
public Transform generationPoint;
public float distanceBetween;

private float platformWidth;

public ObjectPooler theObjectPool;

public float randomEnemyThreshold;
public ObjectPooler enemyPool;

// Käytä alkuarvon alustamiseen
void Start () {
    platformWidth = thePlatform.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().size.x;


}

// Päivitys tulee joka ruutu
void Update () {

    if (transform.position.x < generationPoint.position.x) 
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x + platformWidth + distanceBetween, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);

        //Instantiate (thePlatform, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        GameObject newPlatform = theObjectPool.GetPooledObject();

        newPlatform.transform.position = transform.position;
        newPlatform.transform.rotation = transform.rotation;
        newPlatform.SetActive (true);

        if (Random.Range (0f, 100f) < randomEnemyThreshold) 
        {
            GameObject newEnemy = enemyPool.GetPooledObject();

            Vector3 enemyPosition = new Vector3 (0f, 0.5f, 0f);

            newEnemy.transform.position = transform.position + enemyPosition;
            newEnemy.transform.rotation = transform.rotation;
            newEnemy.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Your enemy prefab probably just needs to have gravity added to it.  Make sure you have a RigidBody attached to the enemy prefab with gravity set up properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking the collider component on the game objects you are spawning. Add a rigid body component on them too as they are using gravity !!

Comment: Thank you. That worked. I just switched to OnCollision instead of OnTrigger and locked Z and X position. But the problem is now that the enemies spawn too close to each other and you can't jump over them.